# How to find theta between 3 circles

Tags: trigonometry, circles

So here's a very ugly sketch of the question I'm trying to solve:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciate! Thank you so much : 3

Comment: Are all the lines going out in the center of the circles?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry that the ugly drawing doesn't properly show that. I wish I knew how to more formally draft this question

Comment: Are D(1), D(3) and D(5) parallel? Try to solve it in "parts" by splitting the angel into 3, connecting D(5) to the edges of the diameters.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that would be done Moti : ( And D1, D2, and D3 are supposed to show that I know the diameter of the circle, and D4 is the distance between the edges of Circles 3 and Circles 4

Comment: You should better defined D5: if it is the minimum distance between the circles then an easy solution can be found, but this don' t correspond to your sketch. Another solution can be found if D5 is the distance between the topmost point of circle 3 and the lowest point of circle 4, but this solution depends upon a coordinate system and so it does not seem to fit your question.

Comment: @Moti how horrible: splitting an angel into 3 pieces... A devil I wouldn't object.

Comment: The solution can not be done by utilizing a single triangle, as result you need to decide what you want to calculate - or the third  side of the triangle that contains the angle (It seems way too complicated) or utilizing existing triangles to and calculate three segments - two by means of a simple $sin(\theta)$ and the third portion by means of the cosine formula

Comment: The actual length of $D_1$ is not relevant. There is not enough information to determine $\phi$ uniquely. To see why this is, imagine that the coloured lines are a freely-jointed framework. You can rotate the smaller circles until the lines $D_3$, $D_4$ and$D_5$ are all collinear, whilst preserving distances, and the requirement for $D_3$ and $D_4$ to be parallel, but changing the value of $\phi$.

Comment: @Parad0x13 Try to make a better picture

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to remake this image. However I'm going to try and use the suggestions above from all of you to solve the problem myself. If I can't solve it I'll probably redo the image and re-ask. Thanks all!